# How do I implement this generic Java interface with a Clojure record?

Tags: clojure, jvm-languages, clojure-java-interop

I'm trying to implement [org.joda.time.ReadableInstant](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html). It inherits from a generic interface, but apparently that shouldn't matter. [The interface](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/1379098f681f0d4d6f0a3403ab6727dc3437b6df/src/main/java/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.java) is:

```
public interface ReadableInstant extends Comparable<ReadableInstant> {
    long getMillis();
    Chronology getChronology();
    DateTimeZone getZone();
    int get(DateTimeFieldType type);
    boolean isSupported(DateTimeFieldType field);
    Instant toInstant();
    boolean isEqual(ReadableInstant instant);
    boolean isAfter(ReadableInstant instant);
    boolean isBefore(ReadableInstant instant);
    boolean equals(Object readableInstant);
    int hashCode();
    String toString();
}
```

My record:

```
(defrecord WeirdDate [year month day]
    ReadableInstant
    (^boolean equals  [this ^Object readableInstant] (.equals (as-date this) readableInstant))
    (^int get [this ^DateTimeFieldType type] (get (as-date this) type))
    (^Chronology getChronology [this] (.getChronology (as-date this)))
    (^long getMillis [this] (.getMillis (as-date this)))
    (^DateTimeZone getZone [this] (.getZone (as-date this)))
    (^int hashCode [this] (.hashCode (as-date this)))
    (^boolean isAfter [this ^ReadableInstant instant] (.isAfter (as-date this) instant))
    (^boolean isBefore [this ^ReadableInstant instant] (.isBefore (as-date this) instant))
    (^boolean isEqual [this ^ReadableInstant instant] (.isEqual (as-date this) instant))
    (^boolean isSupported [this ^DateTimeFieldType field] (.isSupported (as-date this) field))
    (^Instant.toInstant [this] (.toInstant (as-date this)))
    (^String toString [this] (.toString (as-date this))))
```

But I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must hint overloaded method: get
```

Are my type hints wrong? Is there something else wrong?

(Apologies for those of you on the [Clojure mailing list where I've already asked a longer version of this question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/4v9VGcFC5GM/JXHBonWwPXEJ), I thought that a shorter question here might be easier to answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a defrecord to implement a type with a `get` method, because `get` is already defined on java.util.Map, which defrecord automatically implements for you. If you want to implement this interface, you will have to forego the niceties of mappiness and just use a plain deftype. Also, every type hint in your code is completely unnecessary: the compiler knows the types of the interface you're implementing, and doesn't need your help to figure them out.

Comment: Re type annotations, I suspected as much, it's just that the message appeared to be saying 'add more annotations!'.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, that was it. I'm running into another problem, perhaps you could spare a minute? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786493/classnotfound-error-trying-to-implement-clojure-protocol-with-a-deftype