# extend-protocol results in NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: clojure

Related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783142/how-do-i-implement-this-generic-java-interface-with-a-clojure-record), but different.

I'm trying to implement `clj-time.core.DateTimeProtocol` with a `deftype`. I'm using this rather than `defrecord` as the type signatures clash (see [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783142/how-do-i-implement-this-generic-java-interface-with-a-clojure-record)).

I have two files. The first is the implementation and the second is the test. As you see, the test file isn't yet doing anything more than `require`ing the implementation file. Apologies for the code-dump, but this is the minimal working version:

date.clj:

```
(ns util.date
  (:require [clj-time.core :as clj-time])
  (:require [clj-time.core :refer [DateTimeProtocol]])
  (:gen-class))

(defprotocol IWeirdDate
  (as-date [this]))

(deftype WeirdDate [year month day]
  IWeirdDate
  (as-date [this] (clj-time/date-time year month day)))

(extend-protocol DateTimeProtocol
    WeirdDate
    (year [this] (clj-time/year (as-date this)))
    (month [this] (clj-time/month (as-date this)))
    (day [this] (clj-time/day (as-date this)))
    (day-of-week [this] (clj-time/day-of-week (as-date this)))
    (hour [this] (clj-time/hour (as-date this)))
    (minute [this] (clj-time/minute (as-date this)))
    (sec [this] (clj-time/sec (as-date this)))
    (second [this] (clj-time/second (as-date this)))
    (milli [this] (clj-time/milli (as-date this)))
    (after? [this that] (clj-time/after? (as-date this) that))
    (before? [this that] (clj-time/before? (as-date this) that)))

(defn weird-date [y m d] (WeirdDate. y m d))

(def x (WeirdDate. 1986 5 2))
(def y (clj-time/date-time 2014 5 2))

(prn "Loaded OK source" x y)
```

date_test.clj

```
(ns util.date-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [util.date :refer [weird-date]])
  (:require [clj-time.core :as clj-time]))

(def x (weird-date 1986 5 2))
(def y (clj-time/date-time 2014 5 2))

(prn "Loaded OK in test" x y)
```

This breaks with `lein test`, `lein check`, `lein compile` etc.

The strange thing is that the source file seems to work OK:

```
"Loaded OK source" #<WeirdDate util.date.WeirdDate@7e793d7a> #<DateTime 2014-05-02T00:00:00.000Z>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clj_time/core/DateTimeProtocol
```

The problem is elsewhere, for example, in the `ns` declaration of `date-test`. I'm not referencing `DateTimeProtocol` anywhere else.

If I comment out the whole `extend-protocol`, the result is this:

```
"Loaded OK source" #<WeirdDate util.date.WeirdDate@3f19c149> #<DateTime 2014-05-02T00:00:00.000Z>
"Loaded OK source" #<WeirdDate util.date.WeirdDate@5c797bc6> #<DateTime 2014-05-02T00:00:00.000Z>
"Loaded OK in test" #<WeirdDate util.date.WeirdDate@19c6a644> #<DateTime 2014-05-02T00:00:00.000Z>
```

So, it looks like simply referencing this protocol from one namespace is preventing another namespace, that doesn't even mention it, from loading.

What?

Comment: What versions of Clojure and clj-time are you using? How are you building/running the project? This works for me using clj-time 0.8.0 and all recent Clojure versions.

Comment: Lein 2.3.3, clojure 0.8.8. It's strange, it looks like this works within the namespace, it's when I try to access it from another namespace that I get errors. I'm trying to get something reproducible.

Comment: (I'm actually implementing both a Java interface and a Clojure protocol with the same `deftype`.)

Comment: OK @Alex, I just re-wrote the question with something that may be reproducible.

Comment: Actually this looks like it may have been a combination of `aot` and `gen-class`. It's working now I've cleared my `target` directory...

Comment: Yeah, the combination of AOT, Java interop, and language features that cause Java classes to be generated (defprotocol, deftype, etc) can cause weird failures. In general, on-disk .class files will take precedence over classes that are dynamically generated.